# The word "beta" still appears in the app offline html

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Programmers kicked me to the app offline screen today and I couldn't help but notice it still had the beta tag on it.

http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm

The url and content looks generic enough but it is also using the old programmers skin.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70790/graduated-sites-show-sketchy-offline-page

Answer (score 4):

We have rolled out customized offline pages for all the graduated SE sites, themed after their parent sites.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update Jin

Answer (score 2):

Right now all the launched SE sites use the "Sketchy" beta offline page. But we're working on having an "official" offline page for every graduated site, matching their main site theme.